# Enum Type Cast, Element Collection issue in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I already found that `eclipseLink 2.5` already fixed `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum` issue.
But, I use `eclipseLink 2.5` and I still get the following issue:

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "STUDENT_TYPE_LINK", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_TYPE")
    private List<StudentType> studentTypeList;

    ....
}
```

stack trace

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.EnumTypeConverter.convertObjectValueToDataValue(EnumTypeConverter.java:160) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectCollectionMapping.postInsert(DirectCollectionMapping.java:2218) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorQueryManager.postInsert(DescriptorQueryManager.java:999) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:494) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:300) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-
```

I download this jar file here

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.5.0/eclipselink-2.5.0.jar
```

Comment: could you show me your StudentType class ?

Comment: @TienNguyen, the left of Student.java code is only getter/setter...

Comment: When does the error occur? Have you checked also that the entried in DB correspond to names in your enum? Could you also post the link to the announcement that the bug was solved?